# How to run a python append list inside jinja2 template

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I am trying to carry out a for loop using python within Jinja2 that will create and append to a list - however I think I may have a syntax issue as code that seems to work fine in native python fails in a Jinja2 template. I'd like some assistance as to what I may be doing incorrectly

At a high level the code will use a list of subnets gathered by aws gather facts, use a number provided in separate yaml file to determine the number of subnets to be appended to a separate list for a for loop to run through and populate a separate yaml file.

```
{% set subnets_to_use = [] %}
{% set number_of_subnets = {{ cluster.master }} %}  <-- #this value is set in another yaml file
{% set list = usable_kops_subnets %} <-- this has been set by gather facts seperately
{% set list_len = list | length %}
{% for i in range(number_of_subnets) %}
{{ subnets_to_use.append(list[(i)%list_len]) }} <-- #appears to fail here
{% endfor %}

{% for etcd_host_id in subnets_to_use[:cluster.master] %}
    - instanceGroup: master-{{ etcd_host_id.availability_zone }}-{{ loop.index }}
      name: {{ etcd_host_id.availability_zone }}-{{ loop.index }}
{% endfor %}
```

> "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'

When I run similar Python code in a python compiler the code appears to work

Eg:

```
x = 400
list = ["string1","str2","str3","str4"]
subnets_to_use = []
list_len = len(list)
for i in range(x):
       subnets_to_use.append(list[(i)%list_len])
print (subnets_to_use)
```

Comment: append all element to `subnets_to_use` before you send `subnets_to_use` to template.

Comment: Thanks for answering - so are you suggesting setting that outside the template?

Comment: it is the most natural method - create all needed data before you send them to template. Template wasn't created to replace Python's code.

Comment: would this make sense to do outside template?

Comment: Python's code should gather all data and then use template to display data. Mixing code in template makes only mess like in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're focusing on the wrong line. Change this line

```
{% set number_of_subnets = {{ cluster.master }} %}
```

to this

```
{% set number_of_subnets = cluster.master %}
```

and then it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following in ansible rather than using python - seems to work. In this instance clusters.node is defined as 3, and I had one subnet that aws gather facts had got. I wanted 3 instances groups created, all with the same subnet.

```
- name: setup of subnet variables on nodes
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    subnets: "{{usable_kops_subnets}}"
    subnet_length: "{{subnets | length }}"
    servers: "{{cluster.node}}"
    slist_nodes: []
  tasks:
  - name: slist_nodes setup
    set_fact:
       slist_nodes: '{{ slist_nodes + [subnets[(item|int + 0) % (subnet_length|int + 0)]] }}'
    loop: "{{range(0,servers|int,1)| list}}"
```

I then run the loop against the "slist_nodes" list e.g

```
{% for subnet in slist_nodes %}

< code>

{% endfor %}
```

which would create 3 instances with the subnet.